# What does "figure to do" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I came across the following phrase in "The Grinder’s Manual" book about poker :

> ...To build a pot with a strong hand which figures to do well vs the
>   ranges our opponents are calling with.

I can't figure out what's the meaning of "figure" in this sentence. None of the definitions I found by googling "define figure" suits. Any ideas?

Comment: Suggest **figures** means **computes** or **reckons** or **estimates**. Look up "figure out".

Comment: please [show what you found or didn't find and why that didn't work for you](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed/5043#5043). You might have to check *several* dictionaries (not just google the the word + define)

Comment: If it's any consolation, the whole sentence seems incomprehensible to me. Anyone who writes a sentence with vs in the middle is suspect. If your transcription is correct, the author of your book would appear illiterate. I'd throw it away. But another time you need to cite your source properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an adapted (ergative) version of this sense given in [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/figure):

> *figure* V intransitive 3. Informal To seem reasonable or expected: "I found my keys in the sofa." "Well, that figures, given that you were
>   sitting there last night."

You could substitute 'promises' for 'figures' in this example, but I'd say that this would be specifying a greater degree of confidence. Paraphrases are ' ... a strong hand which one figures will do well vs ...' and ' ... a strong hand which may be expected to do well vs ...'.